# How to design a neural network with multiple dependent outputs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have built an actor-critic network in tensorflow. I have a question about my actor network layers design. The actor network should generate 2 outputs. The second output is dependent on the first output, i.e. in order to generate the second output, I need to concatenate the input state and the first output and pass them through the network again and then generate the second output.

The following is my design but I'm not sure if I should use the same hidden layer for both of outputs or create separate hidden layers for each output.

```
def get_actor():
    # Initialize weights between -3e-3 and 3-e3
    last_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-0.003, maxval=0.003)

    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(num_states_actor,))
    f = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(inputs)
    out1 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(f)
    outputs1 = layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer=last_init)(out1)
    out2 = layers.Concatenate()([inputs, outputs1])
    f = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(out2)
    out3 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(f)
    outputs2 = 1e-4 + layers.Dense(1, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=last_init)(out3)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=([outputs1, outputs2]))
    # print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Comment: It all depends on what you suppose the underlying causes are. If you think that both predictions/outputs are dependent then I would recommend to have the same hidden layer. On the other hand, if you can input different information or more information (plus the one you already gave) you can create a separate output.

Comment: @coyote Could you please clarify more if I want to use the same hidden layers for my design? I don't know how should I change my current design to share the same hidden layers for both outputs. Thank you.

Comment: There is a more in depth explanation in 'Hands on machine learning ...' from Aurélien chapter 11. It really depends on what inputs and outputs you have, what type they are and what knowledge you already have about the data (i.e. whar hypothesis can you be almost sure of).

Comment: @coyote Thank you for your response. I want to pick the optimal server to serve the incoming task in the minimum amount of time. So, my action includes 2 elements. The first element is to estimate the server ID and the second element is to estimate the amount of resources that server can allocate to the task. These are dependent since first the actor needs to estimate the server ID and then estimates its allocated resources. I'm not sure how to setup my actor network such that learns about two actions at the same time. Thank you.